# What is the easiest way to rearrange pages in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, editing

Mac's Preview can be used to rearange pages in a PDF document by simply [drag-and-dropping](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_rearrange_pdf_pages_preview) the pages around in the side panel. Is there any equivalent tool for Ubuntu? I have noticed, that the Document Viewer, which comes with Ubuntu, also has this nice side panel. However, it cannot be used to manipulate a PDF document. If there is no drag-and-drop solution, what is the easiest way to rearrange pages in a PDF document?

Comment: Perhaps you could: (1) upgrade to a supported version of Kubuntu (2) create a question of your own to seek an updated answer for this problem? If this is something that you're struggling with, there are likely others with the same question who would appreciate finding a solution 

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use PDF-Shuffler.

You can install it via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

As shown in the image, you only have to import the PDF file you want to manipulate and drag & drop the pages in the desired order. It also lets you to rotate the pages in orthogonal angles.

[image]

You can save it in the same file or export it as a different PDF file.

Comment: Have you found a way to drag-and-drop .jpg document in the pdf file?

Comment: Here a thread about it http://askubuntu.com/q/784390/25388

Comment: Just for the info: pdfshuffler is now marked as "transitional package" in APT (tested on Ubuntu 20). It seems to have been superseded by pdfarranger, which is a fork thereof: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/12/pdfarranger-merge-split-rotate-crop-or.html

Comment: pdfshuffler is no longer available, you can use `pdfarranger` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can install PDF-Shuffler using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfshuffler
```

Comment: pdfshuffler is no longer available, you can use `pdfarranger` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to print the PDF to another PDF with a different page ordering. For example, if you want to reverse a 3 page PDF, you enter `3,2,1` under `Pages`.

## Example

[image]

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu >= 19.10, there is PDF Arranger, which is able to do this. Note that it is derived from PDF Shuffler.

To install PDF Arranger using the GUI run `snap-store`, search for "PDF Arranger", and click *Install*:

[image: Software Center screenshot of PDF Arranger]

Or, if you prefer the command line, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install pdfarranger
```

Answer (score 3):

Re-printing as PDF worked for me when I needed to insert the last page at the middle:

[image]

Comment: You have posted an existing answer.

Comment: +1 for the english screen capture ;-)