# How to Merge-and-Reorder Images and PDF pages?

Tags: 16.04, pdf

I want to reorder pages of my PDF document by using implicitly .png/.jpg images in the processing, not by the easiest way as some of you want [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138592/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-rearrange-pages-in-a-pdf-document) about `pdfshuffler` which cannot do this so this is **not duplicate**.
Current extraneous solution requires explicit conversions of images to .pdf

```
convert *.png all_images_here.pdf
pdfshuffler dummy.pdf all_image_here.pdf
```

Goals for implicit .png/.jpg conversions to pdf

1. Pseudocode to have autoconversion of .jpg/.png documents

   ```
   new-pdfshuffler dummy.jpg jummy.png body.pdf
   ```
2. Pseudocode about GUI

   - `pdfshuffler body.pdf`
   - drag-and-drop `dummy.jpg` and `jummy.png` to `new-pdfshuffler`

System: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4 and 4.6

Comment: @Parto Thank you for pointing out the thread! Pdfshuffler cannot have .jpg files as an input into .pdf document so not possible here.

Comment: @Masi Please don't add new issues to your question, keep it clean and to the point. If you have issues with a solution offered to you ask a new question about it or ask below the answer. That edit made this two different questions and would get it closed, it already attracted close votes.

Answer (score 3):

Try PDFChain, pdfsam or Master PDF Editor. You can install PDFChain and pdfsam from Gnome Software, or you can type in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfchain pdfsam
```

Master Pdf Editor is not available in Gnome Software, nor in the old Ubuntu Software Center. You can download the deb package from owner's site and open/install that package with gdebi, synaptic or Gnome Software, or you can type in a Terminal window:

```
wget http://get.code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor-3.6.30_amd64.deb  
sudo dpkg -i master-pdf-editor-3.6.30_amd64.deb  
sudo apt install -f
```

As to compare them in terms of capabilities, that's rather subjective and depends on user's taste for the GUI (graphical interface). I personally find Master PDF Editor to be the most complete pdf editor one can find in linux. It's like the equivalent of Adobe Acrobat in linux, minus some secondary features.

Comment: @Masi: Well, i guess you'll have yo find it by yourself. It has something to do with Insert menu -> Picture.

Comment: I personally hate the PDFChain UI with a *passion* :P

Answer (score 1):

There is PDFMod. It is very simple to use, and does what you want.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pdfmod/

It is old and hasn't been updated for a while, but version 0.9.1-8 still works on my 16.04 system.

Comment: @Masi no idea. I use only PdfMod.

Comment: I get the error when trying to open .pdf document in the program
`Error Loading Document There was an error loading /home/masi/Documents/Homework/1.pdf`. Do you know about it? First startup of the program in 16.04.

Comment: I now remember that there were issues with PDFMod not being able to open some PDF documents, due to a long-standing bug in PDFSharp (see e.g. [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdfmod/+bug/975928)). Apparently, a new version of PDFSharp seems to be able to handle this kind of PDF document.

Comment: PDFMod can certainly not include .jpg files in a PDF document (you originally asked for a simple utility) but the solution for that would be to open the JPG file in an image viewer and print it to a PDF file.

Comment: Did you solve the problem only by upgrading PDFSharp? Is the bug about the older version of PDFSharp only? Can you please provide an overview how you solved the bug.